# Can an algorithm be classified as "unsupervised learning" if there is no "learning" involved?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, unsupervised-learning

Basically, my question is, since unsupervised learning is a type of machine learning, does there need to be some aspect of the machine "learning" and improving based on it's discoveries? For example, if an algorithm is developed that takes unlabeled images and finds associations between them, does it need to improve itself based on those associations to be classified as "unsupervised learning" or is simply reporting those associations good enough to earn that classification?

Comment: Unsupervised learning is often referred to as clustering, and it most contexts these are synonyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, if an algorithm is developed that takes unlabeled images and finds associations between them...

That is the "learning" in "unsupervised learning," so yes, this would be considered unsupervised learning.

> ...does it need to improve itself based on those associations...

No, there's no requirement that the algorithm take what it has learned and improves itself to be considered unsupervised learning. Just analyzing the data set and finding previously unknown associations is enough to be considered unsupervised machine learning. The "unsupervised" distinction is really just that the initial data set is unlabeled.

Comment: I think it is worth adding that "learning" in (un)supervised learning is not related to the fact that your model is supposed to "learn afterwards", but rather, that the task is to "infer some structure, given data". Consequently the **problem** is an usupervised learning, not algorithm. Algorithm can be simply **applied** to unsupervised learning problem.